# get image title and append to end of current URL for link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using dynamic content in PHP and I need to get the image title and then append that to the end of the current URL.  When the user clicks the image they'll be sent to that destination.

For instance - www.foo.com/bar/ is the current url. The image title is dynamic "current-image-title".  I need the anchor with the class "item-link" to now use "www.foo.com/bar/current-image-title" when the user clicks the image

```
    <a class="item-link" href="new-category">
     <img id="item-desc" src="image.jpg" title="dynamic-title">
    </a>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
     var link = $('#item-desc').each(function() {
      $(this).attr('title');

      $('a.item-link').click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
      document.location.href = document.location + '/' + '$link';
    });
    </script>
```

I can figure out how to either get and use the image title or how to append to the end of the URL but I can't seem to figure out how to do both.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$(".item-link").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this), $img = $this.find("img");
  $this.attr("href", $this.attr("href") + "/" + $img.attr("title"));
});
```

Try it on https://jsfiddle.net/gkk9ohca/